# 'createTHead' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTableElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I am trying to create a custom [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) that extends the `HTMLTableElement` class. The code is relatively simple:

```
class DataTable extends HTMLTableElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute(data)));
        const head = this.createTHead();
    }
}

customElements.define('data-table', DataTable, {extends:'table'});
```

The error comes when I try to call `createTHead()`. According to documentation, this is a function of `HTMLTableElement` (which my class extends) and returns an `HTMLTableSectionElement` object. However, I get an error as stated in the title: `createTHead called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTableElement`

I am expecting the `HTMLTableSectionElement` to be created, instead I get the error. I have tried to remove the options from the `define` call, and I get an "Illegal Constructor" error.

Reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/nw3rsjtv/

Comment: FYI, Apple has, since 2016, stated they will never implement these _Customized Built-In Elements_. So **Autonomous Elements** (extend HTMLElement) is all that is supported in the Safari browser. Your error is probably fixed when you move DOM creation to the ``connectedCallback`` See diagram: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman No, they are just not using `is="data-table"`.

Comment: @connexo, So you say Safari **does** support _customized built-in elements_  just not with ``is``?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman No, it supports them with a small polyfill. My message was in reply to *Your error is probably fixed when you move DOM creation to the connectedCallback*

Answer (score 0):

When extending built-in elements, you don't use it with your own tag name.

That is why your current code is giving you

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor: autonomous custom elements must extend HTMLElement
```

Instead, you provide your registered component name in an `is`-attribute:

Change

```
<data-table data="..."></data-table>
```

to

```
<table is="data-table" data="..."></table>
```

Open this in a browser: https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/OJZRbmO

```js
class DataTable extends HTMLTableElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute("data")));
    if (!Array.isArray(this.data)) {
      console.error("data attribute expects an array of objects.");
    }

    const head = this.createTHead();
    for (let k of Object.keys(this.data[0])) {
      console.log(k);
    }
  }
}

customElements.define("data-table", DataTable, { extends: "table" });
```

```html
<!-- Polyfill for browsers that do not support the full web component spec -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ungap/custom-elements@1.1.0/min.js"></script>

<table is="data-table" data="%5B%7B%22header1%22:1,%22header2%22:2%7D%5D"></table>
```